# proof a function is surjective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Most of the Time in order to proof a function is surjective

- we first choose an Arbitrary point belong to Co-domain **(Target Point)**
- Let  (Target Point) = definition of function
- Solve for x
- proof that f(x) = y

in example Like :

```
f : Z×Z→Z×Z deﬁned by the formula f(m,n)= (m+n,m+2n)
```

My Proof was as the Following :

> Let (x,y) ∈ Z×Z  #(this is the target point)
>
> x = m+n solve for n thus n= x-m
>
> y = m+2n solve for m thus m=y-2n
>
> f(m,n) = (x,y)
>
> (m+n,m+2n) = (x,y)
>
> (y-2n + n , y-2n+2n)
>
> (y-n , y)  = (x,y)

I'm stuck here I don't Know I should do to get   **y-n = x**

Comment: the correct term is **surjective**

Comment: You have to solve $(x,y) =  (m+n,m+2n)$ for $(m,n)$. Although they are integer numbers, the procedure to solve as a system of linear equations works.

Comment: You soved for $n$ in terms of $x$ and $m$,  and for $m$ in terms of $y$ and $n$, What you need is to solve for $n$ and $m$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

The function is just a multiplication by a matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\1& 2 \end{pmatrix}$, which has the inverse $\begin{pmatrix} 2& -1\\-1& 1 \end{pmatrix}$ (over the reals, but it works over $\mathbb{Z}$ too, as we have integer coefficients and the determinant $1$).

So to solve $f(x,y) = (m,n)$ we take $x=2m -n, y=-m+n$, and you can just compute the images to see that it checks out that $f(x,y) = (m,n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the first equation from the second.
Thus y - x = n.
Use that value for n in the first equation and solve for m.
Have you not learned how to solve simultaneous equations?

Answer (score 0):

2 linear equations, 2 unknowns.  So solve the *system* of equations. (Just like you did in algebra I).

$m + n = x$.

$m + 2n = y$

> x = m+n solve for n thus n= x-m
>
> y = m+2n solve for m thus m=y-2n

And thus $m = y- 2(x - m)$

.....

So $m = 2x - y$

And $n = x-m = x - (2x - y) = y-x$.

So $f(2x - y, y-x) = ((2x -y) +(y-x), (2x-y) + 2(y-x)) = (x, y)$.

That's it.